# Compressing the size of React Native apps

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

Can someone please specify me the procedures for compressing the app size built on react native.
I referred to many pages on google, hackernoon, and medium but they were too good for me to understand.

Please if someone knows basic and fewer glitch ideas on how to compress react native apps for both Android and iOS with procedures and where to keep the screen files and assets folder.

I tried by following the steps on [medium](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640), detached the iOS and android folders but it was an unsuccessful attempt. 
Please if someone can help me in compressing the app size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily reduce app size . Just go to app/build.gradle and pasted these lines or check these lines
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

enjoy

Comment: Well, it was regarding expo

Comment: Thanks for your input @anwaar. *Please be more specific on how to do this: Install all dependencies of the Expo project except Expo specific libraries*. I already added this comment there something like 4-5 months ago

Comment: And well at that time I was a noob. Now I am a lesser noob so I know the limitation and the procedures

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce your react-native app size by this steps:
1- shrink your app icons and images size as possible as you can
2- go to android/app/build.gradle and make this changes:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // change false to true
]
...
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);
```

its for using hermes engine in bundling js server.
 3-

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false // change false to true
```

the above line causes building seprate apks instead of universal apk. however you can have both seprates and universal by doing following changes :

```
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64" // seprate apks
    }
}
```